# How to fetch all data from 3 tables with condition in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables school ,schooldetails & admission, and i want to get all data in index page how can i do that , i am getting data of school and admission table due to relationship but not of school details kindly check it and help

```html
school

id
name
name
mobile
city


schooldetails
id
school_id(foreign key of school id)
contact_person

admission

id
school_id(foreign key of school_deatils id)
admission_classes
start_date
end_date

My function
public function schoolslist($class='', $city='')
        {
        $schools = Admission::where('admission_classes', 'like', "%{$class}%")->where('status', '1')->orderBy('id','desc')->whereHas('school', function($query) use($city) {
    $query->where('city', 'like', $city);
})->paginate(10);
          return view('frontend.index',compact('schools'));

        }
        my Admission model
        public function School()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\School');
    }
    public function SchoolDetails()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SchoolDetails');
    }
        
        My view
         @foreach($schools as $i => $school)
         {{ $school->School->name}} from user table Ravi
       {{ $school->SchoolDetails->contact_person}} //from school_Details table  No result 
         {{ $school->start_date }} //from admission table  date 11/22/2018
         @enforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SchoolDetails relation should be with school not addmission so remove SchoolDetails() from Admission Model and add it to School Model

**School Model:**

```
public function Admission()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Admission');    
}
public function SchoolDetails()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\SchoolDetails');    \\Edited
}
```

**Admission model**:

```
public function School()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');     
}
```

**SchoolDetails model**:

```
public function School()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\School');     \\Edited
}
```

Then you can change your View accordingly:

```
@foreach($schools as $i => $school)
    {{ $school->School->name}} from user table Ravi
    {{ $school->School->SchoolDetails->contact_person}}  // This Line is changed
    {{ $school->start_date }}
@enforeach
```

Comment: Done as you said , but i want to say  i have one school with one school details but school can have have multiple take 
 admission please check, getting some error

Comment: Edited. So in case of One to Many relation School model will have hasMany relation for admission and Inverse will be belongsTo

Comment: done as you said  i am getting result for these two {{ $school->School->name}}
    {{ $school->start_date }} but Trying to get property of non-object for {{ $school->School->SchoolDetails->contact_phone}}

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: Edited again sorry for this. This time I created a new project and then checked it myself. There was a problem with the SchoolDetails relation. Please see changes

Comment: Thank you soooooo much , i am glad you helped me...again thank youuuuuuuu, please help everyone like the same way you help me ..